# I want date to be displayed in Milliseconds(epoch) format but getting date with timestamp

Tags: java, date, spring-boot, datetime, epoch

```
@Data
public class SampleDate {
   private Date revisiondate;
}

@RequestMapping("/date")
public ResponseEntity<List<SampleDate>> getDateSample()
{
    List<SampleDate> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
    SampleDate sampDate = new SampleDate();
    sampDate.setRevisiondate(new Date());
    listDate.add(sampDate);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(listDate,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

> Output : [{"revisiondate":"2018-12-06T06:06:18.795+0000"}]
>
> Expected Output : [{"revisiondate":1544077577462}]

I'm using Springboot 2.0.3.RELEASE version. In Springboot 1.3.2.RELEASE version im able to achieve this. Have anyone faced this when you upgrade Springboot.

Comment: What makes you want that output? The one you already have is much more readable. The output is in ISO 8601 format, the international standard, so it should be widely accepted.

Comment: Actually we are upgrading our SOA services which is in production(Springboot 1.3.2.RELEASE). so we need to get the same output exactly as in production code.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat), assuming SpringBoot still uses Jackson, it looks like you can specify that the shape of the data should be a number:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
private Date revisiondate;
```

(Admittedly that guide describes it as *seconds* since the Unix epoch, but it gives an example that's milliseconds.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below annotation on top of date field.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER)
private Date revisiondate;
```

As suggested [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat)